# Android studio debug error "Connection refused"

Tags: android

I know this question was asked before but I tried all the suggested solutions and nothing solved my problem yet.
I can't debug Any Android studio (1.5 preview 2) application using Mac Yosemite.

the error I get is:

```
Unable to open debugger port (localhost:8600): java.net.ConnectException "Connection refused":
```

on the debug console I can see error

```
"Debug port is busy"
```

---

I've tried the following with no success:

1. reinstall  jdk 6+7
2. make sure ports 8600+ are open with with kill .
3. reinstall Android studio and make sure SDK location configured.
4. add debuggable true on debug build types.
5. restart the phone with usb debugging enable.
6. restart Android studio and my mac.
7. tried with Build variant debug and release.
8. on emulator I have the same problem.

with eclipse I dont have any issues with debugging my app.
did I miss something?

Comment: have you checked what are the ports are open in mac? `netstat -atp tcp | grep -i "listen"`

Comment: yes, I don't see port 8600+ on the list

Comment: This may work; Just do a try. In Android device monitor tab; click on the process under device tab and click **Stop Process** button which will stop the process which is using 8600 port

Comment: tried also, I had red debug sign stopped it still get Connection refused error

Comment: I have this error on every 1 of 2 tries - even on the emulator! And yet no info about this error! Started to happen after I installed AS 1.5 with the new "show chooser dialog before gradle build".

Comment: Yeah im getting this issue too after i upgraded to 1.5, on ubuntu

Comment: I get this very often now.  Terminal command: `adb kill-server` sometimes works.

Comment: I tried to close AS when this happened and it froze trying to shut down.  I force closed AS, unplugged the USB from my device and ran adb kill-server, which seemed to work.  I'm running 1.5.1 from Dec 2015 on OS X El Capitan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me nothing helped except - Reinstall Android studio and don't choose the option to import your properties from latest Android studio installation. solved the problem.

when I installed and pick the option to import my last installation properties i had the same error again.

Comment: Why was this down voted?  It may not be the answer you want, but it's better than nothing.

Comment: i tired it ,its not the answer .
for me help to open in the same window other project and debug it and then open my desire .

Answer (score 2):

This happens to me after updating to AS 1.4 all the time.
I always kill the server and restart it with following commands.

```
# /path/to/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb.exe
adb.exe kill-server
adb.exe devices
>>> * daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037*
>>> * daemon started successfully*
>>> * 2100000020000001     device
```

Afterwards I can reconnect with the debugger.
If you add adb.exe to the PATH-variable you can run the commands from the built in terminal in Android-Studio.